How can I make multiple active rigid bodies not intersect?
I'm trying to have these active rigid bodies fall into the jar. Though they land on the jar just fine, they intersect each other. How can I have them not intersect?
Here is the file: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/pszks324ab94gxkmfwnlw/stars.blend?rlkey=591zymt1ttlzrrxnwytacua06&st=gow6mfc4&dl=0




How can i have them not collide you mean?

@moonboots I meant collide as in bounce off each other. I'll change it to something less confusing

Put them in different rigid body collections? We can see these collections in your screenshot

@moonboots That causes the stars to fall through the jar

Put the jar in all the collections (press shift)

@moonboots The stars still intersect

if it still doesn't work please share your file

Scale up all the objects, for the moment they are a bit too small and it doesn't help the calculation, then apply the scale and put the origin of all the objects at their geometry.
In the Physics panel put your objects in different "collections" (note that they are not the Outliner collections), put the jar in all the collections (press Shift and click on the different collections):


The problem still persists

I've edited, I hope it helps

I tried to set the origin to geometry, but for some reason the geometry instead moves to where the origin is. This happens even when I use set origin to 3d cursor.

maybe you've confused Origin to Geometry with Geometry to Origin?

Nope. Tried both and they both set the geometry to the origin

it seems to work fine: https://zupimages.net/up/24/29/x44z.gif

I updated blender to 4.1 and it still doesn't work. Weird.
